# Customising loss functions in scikit learn

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, loss-function

How can I customise loss functions in scikit learn? For example, instead of using mean square error, I want to use MSE multiplied by the true value of the sample. I have used the following code snippet:

```
def my_custom_loss_func(y_true,y_pred):
    diff3=(abs(y_true-y_pred))*y_true
    return diff3

clf=RandomForestRegressor(criterion=my_custom_loss_func)
knn=clf.fit(feam,labm)
```

I get the following error:

```
KeyError: <function my_custom_loss_func at 0x000000002EA9CA60>
```

Comment: @franco piccolo what should be the arguments passed to the my_custom_loss_func? Are y_pred and y_true predefined in scikit learn? My label matrix is labm. If I use labm instead of y_true, what should I use instead of y_pred?

Answer (score 1):

You can customize loss functions in scikit learn, for this you need to apply the `make_scorer` factory to your custom loss function like:

```
from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer
score = make_scorer(my_custom_loss_func, greater_is_better=False)
```

In your particular case with Random Forests though you can't customize the criterion, what you could do is to optimize the hyperparameters with `GridSearchCV` and there you could use your custom loss.

Comment: Are you sure about that ? I think it's just that RandomForestRegressor doesn't accept custom criterion..

Comment: True, I just answered in general, now I suggested GridSearchCV for his particular case.

Comment: A make_scorer factory is use for a custom metric (which can be a potential loss function). I think it's important to make the distinction (metric / loss ) , and I'll say that on scikit-learn you can rarely easily use a custom loss function (apart if you touch the source code) , but you can do hyperparameter search using a custom metric.

Comment: Scorer and loss function are different so this is not an answer to OP

Comment: @FrancoPiccolo what should be the arguments passed in to the custom loss function? Are y_true and y_pred predefined in scikit learn? My label matrix is named “labm”. If I use it in place of y_true, what should I use in place of y_pred?